# Microsoft.Reporting.winforms add reference, works locally, but when built in TFS can't find it at compile time

Tags: c#, reportviewer, tfsbuild

I've got a solution we converted from vs2010 to 2013...

Everything works fine on my box...to get it working originally I had to add a reference to Micorsoft.Reportiviewer.Winforms

When I try to do a build in TFS, I get errors like this:

> Web\IReportGenerator.cs (3): The type or namespace name 'WinForms'
>   does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Reporting' (are you missing
>   an assembly reference?)

I tried reading to my main project, no joy... Still work perfectly on my box, check it in to TFS, queue a new build .. errors..

Comment: Inside "References", right-click on Micorsoft.Reportiviewer.Winforms, go to "Properties" and check if "Copy Local" is "True".

Comment: Does the build server have the correct report viewer runtime installed?  For example the 2012 version: http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=35747

Comment: Make sure that your libraries are part of the solution, in a dedicated dependencies folder. Or use NuGet, my preferred way. You can't expect TFS Build Servers to have everything in the same spot as your development PC.

Comment: I tried installing it, no joy, so I got it as a nuget package and that fixed it. If you add it as an answer I'll mark it and upvote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried installing it and it didnt' work.

So I installed the nugget package and that worked great.

> PM> Install-Package microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms
>
> 'Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms 10.0.40219.1'